# Run QEMU inside a chroot

Tags: xorg, qemu

So I've strange ideas sometimes and I had one this week, which you can check out here: https://youtu.be/qOQt6Fxew2s
Essentially, it is X.org running on my Kobo eReader. Since the Kobos have an underlying Linux layer below their high-level Qt UI, it was easy to setup a minirootfs with Alpine Linux and chroot into it to install things.
This is just nonsense, but since I'm able to run Xorg on my Kobo, then I'd also like to emulate things in it! *Like Windows 95 with qemu-system-x86_64*
I installed it on the reader and it reported this error: `qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to bind socket: Address not available`
I highly suspect that this is due to it running in a chroot. For info, the Kobo is sporting a 1 GHz armv7l processor made by Freescale (it's the Freescale Solo Lite, if I remember correctly). I've done bind mounts to /proc, /sys, tmp, etc. , but none of that worked.
Any idea on how to launch QEMU? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a working network stack? Can you `ping 127.0.0.1` for example?

Comment: Well... no! What would be next to do then?

Comment: It works! Thanks! I was just being dumb not realizing that ```lo``` interface was not up in ```ifconfig```

Comment: @NicolasMailloux If you have an answer to your question, please put it into the Answer box below so that future readers can find it (and the system knows that this question has been answered). Thank you!